# Problem in Internal redirection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have set the .htaccess redirection as follow

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/(.[0-9]|[1-9])-(.*).htm
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.[0-9]|[1-9])-(.*).htm ./myfile.php?id=$2&dir=$1&title=$3 [L]
```

its working fine for urls like

```
"http://domain/funny/23-some-title.htm" 
"http://domain/funny/45-some-title.htm"
```

It doesn't work if the numeric value greater than 100. Can anybody tell me the problem... 
Still I'm trying to solve the solution.

Comment: I think the problem is that `[0-9]|[1-9]` allows for 2 digit numbers only. I leave it up to someone else to suggest a solution. My regex knowledge is not so strong.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can try to use `[0-9]+` in place of `[0-9]` so that anything from more than a single digit gets selected.

You can give it a try..